# Posição da linha e coluna que foi clicada dentro do RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Eu tenho uma aplicação simples que somente faz a leitura de um arquivo e retorna o que tem nele dentro de um richtextbox.
O Ponto é quando eu clicar na dentro do richtextbox, teria que me voltar a posição da linha e coluna onde ele foi clicado, igual a funcionalidade de um notepad normal como mostra na figura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui pegar a linha e a posição atraves da função mousedown.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

existe algum metodo já pronto que retorne a coluna ?
Procurei na documentação da microsoft mas não achei.

código que eu já fiz até agora

```
private void rtbVisualizar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int pos = rtbVisualizar.SelectionStart;
    int linha = rtbVisualizar.GetLineFromCharIndex(pos);
    lblLC.Text = $"Linha: {linha + 1} | Coluna:  | Posição: {pos + 1}";
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Tentou o `CaretPosition`?
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Achei a Solução!
Na variavel pos eu pego a posição total na qual se encontra o ponto que foi clicado.
Na variavel linha eu eu pego o a linha na qual se encontra o ponto clicado,
Na varivel col eu faço uma subtração entre a posição clicada e o primeiro index da linha. assim retornando o valor da coluna clicada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void rtbVisualizar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int pos = rtbVisualizar.SelectionStart;
    int linha = rtbVisualizar.GetLineFromCharIndex(pos);
    int col = rtbVisualizar.SelectionStart - rtbVisualizar.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(linha);
    
    lblLC.Text = $"Linha: {linha + 1} | Coluna: {col + 1} ";
}
```